Solved - Remove excel password using SSIS & C#
I need to remove the excel password and save (without password) using Interop, so the other processes can read the excel files file without issue. I tried the below code which I found in google but its not removing the password.
Please note, am new to both SSIS and C# and have limited knowledge.
public void Main()
{
        string excelFile = "D:\\Data\\FX File\\ZZ_All_Files\\Input\\SSIS Test PWD.xlsx";
        
        Application xl = new Application();
        Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(excelFile, Password: "ssistest");
        wb.Unprotect("ssistest");
        wb.Save();
        wb.Close();
        xl.Quit();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

code is running fine, but password is not removed from excel workbook. I tried using SaveAs with different file name, but still its not working.

Removing passwords is quite a gray area, you might want to explain (in your post by editing it) why the password needs to be removed.

@excellor - I need to consume the excel data for other internal application for reporting purpose and develop KPIs.

That code will only work if the spreadsheet password *is "ssistest". There are ways to remove password protection from Excel sheets that rely on opening it as a ZIP file and finding and eliminating the passwords. This arises quite often in benign office settings where someone who has left password protected parts of a sheet to prevent accidental damage by users but is no longer around to ask what it is. Removing passwords from VBA modules is another matter entirely.

Working code with few mofications
public void Main()
{
    Excel.Application ExcelApp;
    Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook;
    string excelFile = "D\\Data\\Files\\SSISTestPwd.xlsx";
    ExcelApp = new Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Object pwd = "ssistest"
    ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile,ReadOnly:false,Password: 
    pwd);
    ExcelWorkbook.Password = null;
    ExcelWorkbook.Save();
    ExcelWorkbook.Close();
    ExcelApp.Quit();
}   


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You have to open the Excel file in Edit Mode.
The second argument in SpreadSheetDocument.Open should be set to true.
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

class Test
{

static void Main()
{
    string filePath = @"E:\test.xlsx";
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
        Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

        var dataBeforeProtection = workSheet.Descendants<Row>().First().Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue.InnerText;
        workSheet.RemoveAllChildren<SheetProtection>();
        var dataAfterProtection = workSheet.Descendants<Row>().First().Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue.InnerText;
        workSheet.Save();
    }
}

}

Many thanks, code is working as expected after changing the readonly to false
